# Replace the missing values in SAS

Tags: sas

I want to replace the missing values with the next variables by pushing the values towards H1, Please see the example below. I have placed the desired output below.
                                  b

```
SN     OP_NAME  H1  H2  H3  H4  H5
115060  NORS    .   2331            
115060  WIDE    .               
115061          .               
115061  AIR     .   7680            
115061  ALLI    .               
115061  SKYW    1594                
115062  NORS    .   .           
115062  WIDE    3130    .           
115063  NORS    .   5414            
115063  WIDE    .               
115064  ATLA    5231    .   11259   .   
115066  ATLA    9637    .   5191    .   
115067  LUXA    .               
115069  ATLA    .   5963    .       
115070  AMER    7457                
115070  ATLA    10181               
115070  WEST    .               
115072  JETS    10517               
115073  SKYW    .   .   5515    .   .
115074  MIDW    .               
115075  SKYW    .   .   4291    3499    11549
115076  DLTN    3918
```

Output looks like:`

```
SN     OP_NAME  H1  H2  H3
115060  NORS    2331        
115060  WIDE    .       
115061          .       
115061  AIR     7680        
115061  ALLI    .       
115061  SKYW    1594        
115062  NORS    .   .   
115062  WIDE    3130    .   
115063  NORS    5414        
115063  WIDE    .       
115064  ATLA    5231    11259   
115066  ATLA    9637    5191    
115067  LUXA    .       
115069  ATLA    5963        .
115070  AMER    7457        
115070  ATLA    10181       
115070  WEST    .       
115072  JETS    10517       
115073  SKYW    5515    .   
115074  MIDW    .       
115075  SKYW    4291    3499    11549
115076  DLTN    3918
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cheeky double proc transpose ought to do the trick (the first datastep is some test code):

```
data test_code;
  serial=1; h1=3; h2=.; h3=55; output;
  serial=2; h1=.; h2=.; h3=32; h4=.; output;
  serial=3; h1=45; h2=23; h3=.; h4=99; output;
  serial=4; h1=.; h2=.; h3=5; output;
proc sort;
  by serial;
run;

proc transpose data=test_code out=test_code_tran(drop=_:);
  by serial;
  var h:;
proc transpose data=test_code_tran prefix=h out=final_output(drop=_:);
  by serial;
  var col1;
  where col1;
run;
```

As programmed above though, it will only work with numeric values in the `h*` variables

Comment: Note, the way you did it above you'll need `by serial op_name`, and if you have duplicates of op_name inside a serial you risk combining rows.

Comment: @Joe has a point - I am assuming your `serial optname` variables form a 'primary key' (i.e. are unique for each row).  If not, create one by adding `id = _n_;` in your datastep and using the `id` variable in the `by` statements above.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is probably a double-counter loop.

```
data want;
set have;
array hs h:;
_counter=2;
do _t = 1 to dim(hs)-1 while (_counter le dim(hs));
  if missing(hs[_t]) then do;
    do while (missing(hs[_counter]));
      _counter+1;
      if _counter > dim(hs) then leave;
    end;
    put _t= _counter=;
    if _counter le dim(hs) then do;
      hs[_t] = hs[_counter];
      call missing(hs[_counter]);
      _counter+1;
    end;
  end;
end;
run;
```

The PROC TRANSPOSE option is less code and more flexible; this may be faster if you have a ton of rows.

Answer (score 2):

In a similar method to Joe's, I'd use arrays for this kind of processing...

```
%LET NVARS = 5 ;

data want ;
  set have ;
  array _t{&NVARS} _TEMPORARY_ ;
  array _n H1-H&NVARS ;

  t = 0 ;
  /* Load non-missing values into temporary array */
  do i = 1 to dim(_n) ;
    if not missing(_n{i}) then do ;
      t + 1 ;
      _t{t} = _n{i} ;
    end ;
  end ;

  /* Load temporary array back into source array */
  call missing(of _n{*}) ;
  do i = 1 to t ;
    _n{i} = _t{i} ;
  end ;

  drop i t ;
run ;
```